# Multiple vs one big context_processor

Tags: django, performance, django-context

I have multiple `context processor` and in each I have to request the user. Each of these look like this:

```
def UploadForm(request):
  user = request.user
  Uplo = UploadForm(request.POST or None, initial={user})
  return {'Uplo': Uplo}
```

I saw that this is not efficient since im requesting the user multiple times, so I thought about writing one big `context processor` where I define all the Forms at once.

```
def AllForms(request):
  user = request.user
  Uplo = UploadForm(request.POST or None, initial={user...})
  SetForm = SetForm(request.POST or None, initial={user...})
  ...
  return {'Uplo': Uplo,'SetForm': SetForm}
```

Can anybody tell me if I gain here anything? What is the common standard for context processors? I could not find anything on SO.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think it is inefficient to request the user multiple times.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Isn't any request bad in terms of performance? I'm a beginner and probably put too much weight into things like this but the context_prcessors are called every time so I wanted  to keep them as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Getting user from request is not a big thing. It is o(1) operation.

However if the multiple context processors are not doing different thing and can be don at one time, it should be better to create one big context processor as you say it. The reason being you have to get in and out of the function multiple times in same request.

Anyway if you want definitive difference, you can just print time in multiple and clubbed context processors.

And yes, if you are hitting the database every time, you should club them and optimise the number of times you have to hit the db.